# Pelican ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'j'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, pelican

I’m using Pelican to set up a static site. When I try to generate it, I get the following error: `CRITICAL: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'j'`

The command I used is `pelican content -s pelicanconf.py`.

This is my [pelicanconf.py](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/306c8833fdf2e89ccce3bc7d9d48c42b#file-pelicanconf-py). This is my [requirements.txt](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/306c8833fdf2e89ccce3bc7d9d48c42b#file-requirements-txt). I'm using Python 3.6 in a virtual environment.

What is this module named ‘j’?

edit: I think I’m setting line 81 wrong: 
`JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {'extensions': 'jinja2.ext.i18n'}`. What is the proper way to set this?

Answer (score 0):

I was right, it is line 81. This should be:

`JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n']}`